# How to create a centered pane bootstrap with elements inside

Tags: html

I was wondering how to achieve this with html/css. Image attached below with the kinda idea I was going to do.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Who upvoted this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS stylesheet. To center an text/element inside a div use

```
.center {
text-align: center;
}
```

To center an element such as a div on the DOM use

```
.center {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```